# mod_perl2 with apache 2.22 Apache2::RequestIO::print: (103) Software caused connection abort

Tags: apache, mod-perl, apache2.2, mod-perl2

I’m trying to get a mod_perl2 application ported to AWS. As part of the port I thought I’d move from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy with the latest stable mod_perl & Apache2 combination.

The application works right up to the point I try and write JSON responses to the client. At this point, each request is canceled on the client and on the server I get the error

```
Apache2::RequestIO::print: (103) Software caused connection abort
```

whenever I write to the client, i.e.:

```
$self->req->print($output);
```

I’ve tried `tcpdump`ing the response to the client, and I can see it being written out, but no response is received on the client end and it just barfs chips. I can’t find any information on how to get around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I found quite a few people asking about this question on the net without many answers. The solution to my problem was very specific but I thought I’d post what I did anyway, it may help someone.*

The client was canceling the request before the response was fully written, which was crapping out Apache::RequestIO (for reasons I still don’t know).
I couldn’t work out why I was seeing this behavior.

By using `tcpdump` I could see that data was being written out to the client – and it looked fine.

By inspecting the page in Chrome and looking at the network stack, I could see that my request for data was being canceled after no response was received (which was odd because the code worked fine on other servers and I could see the response was being written). Debugging was may harder because with Apache crashing out with an error in print IO I couldn’t check if the bytes written equaled the bytes of data. I wasn’t sure if something was getting stuck on the server side.

So, I changed the Content-Type of the response from `application/json` to `text/html`, so that I could query the page and just look at the actual response as text. Once I did that, I could see that the response was fine.

I started to look for other causes, and I found that in the migration to the new server, I’d missed altering some URLs in the DB to point to the new server, which meant **my application was trying to get some data from the old DB.
This in turn was causing a load of timing issues, which was causing my problems. Once I fixed the config, the problems went away.**